# Expected behaviour of map function in collection

Tags: laravel, collections, eloquent

I am using `map()` function to perform a logic on each item in the collection:

```
$result = $payments->map(function($payment){

         $payment = app('App\Service\Service1')::sendPayment();

         if(!payment){
            return false;
         }

         $payment = Payment::findOrFail($payment->id);
         $payment->sent_at = Carbon::now();
         $payment->save();
});
```

Question:

If sending the payment fails I am checking with if statement in that case I return false.

So I am expecting when I return false on `map()` function to skip that current item in collection and process the next one? Is that the right behaviour of `map()` function and what is the difference with `each()`

Answer (score 0):

The `each` method iterates over the items in the collection and passes each item to a callback:

```
$collection = $collection->each(function ($item, $key) {
    //
});
```

If you would like to stop iterating through the items, you may return `false` from your callback:

```
$collection = $collection->each(function ($item, $key) {
    if (/* some condition */) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

The `map` method iterates through the collection and passes each value to the given callback. The callback is free to modify the item and return it, thus forming a new collection of modified items:

```
$collection = collect([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);

$multiplied = $collection->map(function ($item, $key) {
    return $item * 2;
});

$multiplied->all();

// [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```